# regarding stripslash in html pages how to hide... in php pages

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

when i add the enter from the CMS admin panel then add the data before doing this php method..

```
$result = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

because i have too much special characteres in the db records, but stripslashes also show on the php pages how to decode stripslash or hide those. . thanking in advance.

please let us know any good function of php... thanks

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. So, you do the right thing and escape any strings on INSERT. Then, on retrieval, you remove the slashes using stripslashes()? And you want to not use stripslashes?

Comment: Can you describe in detail what your actual problem is?

Comment: Sounds like you're on a host that has magic_quotes_gpc enabled. Since they're obviously living in the dark ages, I'd suggest finding a new host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform *database* escaping **when entering data into the database**, and no sooner.  Escape a **copy** of the data, as it's being entered into the database.  Don't modify the original.

Remember, the methods used to escape data for entry into a database are *entirely different things* than the methods used to sanitize user-provided input for display.  Perform them at appropriate times, and don't mix them in your code.

If you're having to use `stripslashes`, then something is wrong with your code.  You either double-escaped, or you have a server misconfiguration resulting in "magic quotes" being enabled.

Comment: hi charles, following are the data support i entered Can't then in the database records its show Can\'t and when i display it then its show stripslash also... I call this method mysql_real_escape_string because you know i also have to generate product xml ... !!

Comment: got it .. !! stripslashes function save my life .. !! thanks charles you are too helpfull thanks soo much

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1) turn off magic quotes.
2) forget about stripslashes
3) use proper escaping using mysql real escape and passing the resource to the function and not just the string.

Comment: what is magic quotes, what do mean by stripslashes and regarding my question i said i haave to much special charachers in the database records.